# sql count all items that day until start of database isn't working because of time

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to count each item in a database table, that is deployments.  I have counted the total number of items 3879, by doing this:

```
use Bamboo_Version6
go
SELECT Count(STARTED_DATE)
FROM [Bamboo_Version6].[dbo].[DEPLOYMENT_RESULT]
```

But I have been struggling to get the number of items each day until the start.  I have tried using some of the other similar answers to this like:

```
select STARTED_Date, count(deploymentID)
from [Bamboo_Version6].[dbo].[DEPLOYMENT_RESULT]
WHERE STARTED_Date>=dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,STARTED_Date)- 7,0)
GROUP BY STARTED_Date
```

But this will return every id, and a 1 beside it because the dates have times which are making it unique, so I tried doing this: `CONVERT(varchar(12),STARTED_DATE,110)` to try and fix the problem but it still happens.  How can I count this without, getting all the id's or every id as 1 each time?

Comment: did you replace *both* `STARTED_DATE` in the query with  `CONVERT(varchar(12),STARTED_DATE,110)` ? - If you just did it in the select you won't get what you want.

Comment: convert(date, STARTED_Date) will remove the time part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the time component:

```
select cast(STARTED_Date as date) as dte, count(deploymentID)
from [Bamboo_Version6].[dbo].[DEPLOYMENT_RESULT]
group by cast(STARTED_Date as date)
order by dte;
```

I'm not sure what the `WHERE` clause is supposed to be doing, so I just removed it.  If it is useful, add it back in.

Comment: Gordon, is there a reason for chosing cast(field as type) over convert(type, field) or does it makes no difference ?

Comment: @GuidoG . . . It doesn't make a difference.  I learned `cast()` a long, long time ago, so I tend to use that.

Answer (score 0):

I have another efficient way of doing this, may be try this with an over clause

```
   SELECT cast(STARTED_DATE AS DATE) AS Deployment_date,
        COUNT(deploymentID) OVER (  PARTITION BY cast(STARTED_DATE AS DATE) ORDER BY STARTED_DATE) AS NumberofDeployments
    FROM [Bamboo_Version6].[dbo].[DEPLOYMENT_RESULT]
```